# Errors reading CSV with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, large-data

I have a dataset of 100 million rows that I need to analyze. I use this function to read the file:

```
csv2020=pd.read_csv('filename.txt',
                    sep="\t",
                    error_bad_lines=False,
                    usecols=['field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'field4'],
                    dtype={'field1': int,'field2': float, 'field3': float, 'field4': float})
```

But I'm getting an error about one of the lines not possible to convert to a float:

**ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ORCH'**

I would like to omit any lines where this error occurs, but I don't know how besides the error-bad-lines argument. Help?

Thanks!

Comment: as `filename.txt` contains 100 million rows - do you think that you have enough memory to load it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `error_bad_lines` option is not for this purpose, it only applies to an incorrect number of fields.

Read your file without the `dtype` option and do the conversion afterwards using [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with the `errors='coerce'` option:

```
df = pd.read_csv(…)
df['field1'] = pd.to_numeric(df['field1'], errors='coerce')
df['field2'] = …
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the columns you are trying to import as float has strings and therefore cannot be converted.

Read the CSV first without the "dtype...." and look at your dataframe